# Not able to get oauth2 token information from google api

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm able to get access oauth2 token from google api by using below code:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script>
  var YOUR_CLIENT_ID =
'568020407566-s1tdctjbjeocf5nt20l64midfo1atu4h.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var YOUR_REDIRECT_URI =
'https://us-central1-hyperledger-poc.cloudfunctions.net/oauthjax';
  var fragmentString = location.hash.substring(1);

  // Parse query string to see if page request is coming from OAuth 2.0 server.
  var params = {};
  var regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
  while (m = regex.exec(fragmentString)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }
  if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
    localStorage.setItem('oauth2-test-params', JSON.stringify(params) );
    if (params['state'] && params['state'] == 'try_sample_request') {
      trySampleRequest();
    }
  }

  // If there's an access token, try an API request.
  // Otherwise, start OAuth 2.0 flow.
  function trySampleRequest() {
    var params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oauth2-test-params'));
    if (params && params['access_token']) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET',
          'https://www.googleapis.com' +
          'access_token=' + params['access_token']);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhr.response);
        } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 401) {
          // Token invalid, so prompt for user permission.
          oauth2SignIn();
        }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
    } else {
      oauth2SignIn();
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create form to request access token from Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
   */
  function oauth2SignIn() {
    // Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint for requesting an access token
    var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

    // Create element to open OAuth 2.0 endpoint in new window.
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'GET'); // Send as a GET request.
    form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

    // Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
    var params = {'client_id': YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
                  'redirect_uri': YOUR_REDIRECT_URI,
                  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                  'state': 'try_sample_request',
                  'include_granted_scopes': 'true',
                  'response_type': 'token'};

    // Add form parameters as hidden input values.
    for (var p in params) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      input.setAttribute('name', p);
      input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
      form.appendChild(input);
    }

    // Add form to page and submit it to open the OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  }
</script>

<button onclick="trySampleRequest();">Try sample request</button>
</body></html>
```

I'm trying to get the token information using `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 mentioned in below google document`

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken

I'm getting below error as response:

```
{
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

But if i use the same token to get user info, it was working fine by using below code and the response as well

code which i tried:

```
const token = req.body.access_token;
 var options = {
    host: 'www.googleapis.com',
    port: 443,
    //path: '/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
    path: '/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token='+token,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token}
  }
  // making the https get call
  let data;
  var getReq = await https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
      console.log("line 52");
     // var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("line 54"+data);
      res.send(data);
     // console.log('data', parsed);
   //   console.log('endSTATUS: ' + parsed);

    });
  });
  //  console.log("response",recievedJSON);
  /*getReq.on('end',function(){
   res.send(valid);
  });*/
  getReq.end();
  getReq.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  });
```

**Response:**

```
{
      "sub": "1070944556782450037456",
      "picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-b32hSj9vONg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/tasdfsadfBfIQ/photo.jpg",
      "email": "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      "email_verified": true
    }
```

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com' + 'access_token=' + params['access_token']);  <--- i think you rmissing the ? before access_token.  But really you should be setting that as an autorization header bearer token and not sending it inline.

Comment: if you see the sample code in the google doc link, they are sending it as inline

Comment: sounds like you are implying that there could not be a error in the sample code you are following.  

Comment: I’m not implying... I don’t have sample code to get the token info. I’m just trying url directly in the browser

Comment: 'https://www.googleapis.comaccess_token=' + params['access_token']); and 
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123  are not the same URL what exactly do you want to achieve here comparing two different things?   The first isnt even a valid url

Comment: When I pass the  generated token here https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 it throws invalid, when I pass in googleapis.com I’m able to retrieve information, that means token which is generated is valid

Comment: try access_token= instead of Id_token assuming that you have a valid access token its not the same as an Id_token

Comment: I have tried it too, any idea how accesstoken and idtoken are different ???

Comment: Access token your drivers licence,   Id token your birth certificate.   One gives you Authorization to access something the other identifies you as a person.   Again what exactly is it you are trying to do? Do you just want to get the current logged in users profile info?  If so why not follow this https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs